# Define a module inside a module

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Having the following module:

```
module Foo
end
```

How can we add inside this `Foo` module another module from its name (with for example: `name = 'Bar'`)?

I would like to dynamically get this:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean, "dynamically add"?

Comment: yup @sergio-tulentsev, just adding a module inside a module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without (ugly) string eval:

```
module Foo
end

bar = Module.new
Foo.const_set(:Bar, bar)
```

Comment: Yes, but with string eval, you loose a lot of information and have to reinterpret everything. Imagine `name` being `"Foo Bar"`. Have fun debugging that.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty straightforward:

```
module Foo
end

name = 'Bar'

Foo.class_eval <<RUBY
  module #{name}
  end
RUBY

puts Foo::Bar
# >> Foo::Bar
```

Comment: Thanks. But `class_eval` is brutal. I would prefer to do it with simple metaprogramming methods, rather than a string contening some Ruby code.

Comment: String eval is as simple as it can get. :)

Answer (score -2):

You just write it:

```
# In some part of your codebase:
module Foo
end

# Extension:
module Foo
  module Bar
  end
end
```

Comment: I suppose it's about not reading the most important word, `dynamically`, which means that part of the information, like the name of the inner module, is given in a variable.